# Is it possible to detect streaming download?

Tags: video, download, streaming, detect

I'm working on a website that provides streaming video classes (online courses, like moodle), but only for registered members.

Is that possible to detect if a user is downloading a video instead of just watching it? I mean, i know i can't actually prevent downloads, screen capture or camcorders, but is it possible to detect capture softwares, like IDM, or browser addons/extensions/plugins? I also know i can't forbid addons, but can i detect if they are being used?

I'm asking this because the access to the website is paid and for a limited time, and downloading videos from the streaming server is against the terms of service.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe from headers or javascript?

Comment: I think everything is possible. This one maybe with some privacy violations, but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You CANNOT detect if your users are downloading or coping the stream or screen capturing from the server at all. If that would be the case, you could even detect what they are watching on the screen or typing !

You can detect capture softwares though, if you force your users to download and install it in their computers (which I think wont be practical anyway).

If you still want to protect your videos, DRM will be your last hope.